# Как организовать очередь последовательно выполняющихся задач?

Tags: java

Задача стоит следующая.

> Есть очередь задач. Необходимо создать поток которому периодически эти задачи будут приходить.

на ум приходит следующий механизм. Создать класс-наследник от Thread и в методе run сделать приблизительно следующее :

```
while(!isInterrupted()) {
    while(executedTask != null) {
        // execute task
        // push callback about successfully processed task
        executedTask == null;
    }
}
```

Но, глядя на код, интуиция подсказывает, что кто то мне "руки за такое отобьёт" :)

Поэтому и хочу поинтересоваться, как **лучше** и **правильней** реализовать данную задачу. Можно без кода, просто словами. Буду благодарен на ссылки с примерами.

```
------------------     -------------------
|   TaskHolder   |     |   WorkerThread  |            
------------------     -------------------
        |                        |
 task   |      execute           |
------->|----------------------->|
 task#2 |              hard-time task worked
------->|queue task until current|
        |task is processed       |
 task#3 |                        |
------->|queue task until current|
        |task is processed       |
 task#4 |                        |
------->|queue task until current|
        |task is processed       |
 task#5 |                        |
------->|queue task until current|
        |task is processed       |
 task#6 |                        |
------->|queue task until current|
        |task is processed       |
        |                        |
        |                        |
        |                 task finished
        |    return result       |
        |<-----------------------|
        |                        |
        |pop task#2 from queue   |
        |      execute task#2    |
        |----------------------->|
               .   .    .
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Например, вот так и добавлять в него задачи

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        final int num = i;
        System.out.println("Send task " + num);
        service.submit(()->{
            try {
                System.out.println("Start thread " + num);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Finish thread " + num);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    service.shutdown();
}
```